# Bower: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted

Tags: npm, bower

After running `bower install` no libraries are getting downloaded and I am getting `Error: EPERM: operation not permitted`. I tried this on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `npm cache clean` solved my issue. [Ref.](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10826)